# Undefined Local Variable 'search_path' in my view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error says that there is an undefined local variable 'search_path', how would i fix this?

My view file a.k.a app/views/_search_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, method: 'get') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :keyword, 'Search', size: '20', id: 'keyword' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

And my routes.rb file a.k.a config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/" => "main_app#index"
  get "/location" => "location#location"
  post "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/directions" => "location#directions"

  root to: 'questions#index'

  resources :questions do
    collection do
      get :your_questions
    end
  end

  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :questions, except: [:new] do
  resources :answers, only: [:create]
  end

  get '/register', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  # get '/questions/your_questions', to: 'questions#your_questions' original
  get '/questions/:id', to: 'questions#show'
```

Comment: What is `search_path` supposed to be?

Comment: There is nothing in your `routes.rb` to indicate what `search_path` is supposed to be.

Comment: @JTG how do i fix it then?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a controller and an action that you would like to map to `search_path` you could put this line in your `routes.rb`.

```
get 'search', to: 'controller#action', as: :search
```

And this will create `search_path` which will return `/search`, which is mapped to `controller#action`.

[Read more about it here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

But you need to have a controller and an action to submit your search form to.  I don't know enough about your app to help you with that.